# Is it allowed to use the same static void function to use multiple threads in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I think that the question is pretty self-explanatory, however here is an example of what I am referring to. say we have

```
static void *foo(void * bar) {

    //some random function/method/calculation/data manipulation.

}
```

is it safe/possible to create multiple threads and use that same function? I have a very lengthy file (approaching 1000 lines) Its starting to get lengthy to scroll up and down. long story short I can't afford errors or unintended functioning. Or would my better bet be to simply create another C file? my mutexing and everything is solid. so I'm not too worried.

```
int main() {
Is something like this feasable?: 

    pthread_t A1, A2;
    pthread_creat(&A1, NULL, foo, &foobar);
    pthread_create(&A2, NULL, foo, &foobar);
    
    pthread_join(A1, NULL);
    pthread_join(A2, NULL);
}
```

if i choose to head into this route any advice/precautions?

Comment: Yes it's fine. Are you thinking it's a problem because static variables inside a function are in general unsafe when multithreading? A static function is not the same as a local static variable -- a static function has visibility only in the file it's declared, whereas a static variable has a value that persists.

Comment: Passing the same function to multiple threads is standard practice when creating workers and similar, so it's not only feasible, but pretty usual.

Comment: I am new to C and I need to finish up this program, I had run into this question because I was worried that the thread(s) would act as one, or in similar manner. causing confliction and error(s). However since this is threadsafe (at least it sounds like for the most part) I just need to figure out a good way to change variables such that I can manipulate which threads it is that I need to.

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time to answer my question everybody, however the question still remains is there anything that i should keep in mind and watch out for? As well as for my second question since this is standard practice in C anyways should I take down this question?

Comment: @itsMe: proper thread programming is non-trivial to say the least. The answer to your question is yes, it is possible to pass the same function to different threads executing in parallel, but the devil is in the detail of how you deal with accessing shared data from those threads.  Such a discussion far exceeds what can be explained in a comment or in an answer. Without any information as to what data manipulation is performed, no clue can even be given as to how or even what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code is constant in C, so there is no problem for multiple threads to use the same functions. What matters is the use of data by these functions: any access to shared modifiable data must be protected.

Note that some functions such as `strtok()` store their context in hidden static data and thus may not be thread safe.

In your example you pass the address of the same `foobar` object. Unless this object is constant throughout the lifetime of both threads, there would be concurrent access to shared modifiable data which would require special handling with locks or other forms of synchronisation.

A few thousand lines is not a lot of data, a single thread is a **much** simpler approach to your problem. Unless the processing of this data is very CPU intensive, multiple threads will create more problems for little benefit.

Proper thread programming is non-trivial to say the least. The answer to your question is yes, it is possible to pass the same function to different threads executing in parallel, but the devil is in the detail of how you deal with accessing shared data from those threads.  Such a discussion far exceeds what can be explained in an answer. Without any information as to what data manipulation is performed, no clue can even be given as to how or even what to do.

Comment: I was thinking of having a loop and manipulating foobar and passing off what i need into each thread is that a feasable option?

Comment: @itsMe: It is possible, but potentially very tricky. What makes you think multiple threads will help? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I need multiple threads to utilize limited resources to get a hefty load of stuff done, and I need to ensure that it doesn't deadlock. I was thinking of passing threadNo as an int into foobar.

Comment: I basically just need to keep track of each thread because I have a number of global arrays that they need to manipulate and passing in the threadNo helps me keep track of array indexes that i need to manipulate as well as like i said previously enter in code to ensure that it doesn't deadlock.

Comment: My advice is don't use threads, especially if your problem involves global arrays.

Comment: To (mis)quote Sacha Guitry: *Les threads, c'est résoudre à deux les problèmes qu'on n'aurait pas eus tout seul.*

Comment: see the problem there is that i need there to be multiple processes running and live feedback

Comment: Multiple processes does not necessarily imply multiple threads in the same process.